# Decoding a regex

Tags: java, regex

I am looking to decode a regular expression.
Is there a way to check what the below regex means:

```
^(PC([Y\\d])|GC([Y\\d])|Y|\\d)\\d{4,5}$
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the Regular Expression Analyzer at http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws or http://www.debuggex.com/

---

```
^ = start of string
() = capturing groups
[] = character classes
\d = digit in 0-9
\\ = literal backslash
| = OR
{} = count of leading item
$ = end of string
```

Comment: Sorry. I am new to regex. Can you please help me understand what is the significance of grouping in regex.

Comment: @user179516 Which particular part are you having trouble with?

Comment: PC([]) and GC([]) groups are looking similar to me. I am trying to understand why we have added two groups here.

Comment: @user179516 They are, but they are separated by `|`, which is the OR. The `[]` matches any of the characters inside it, once.

Comment: @user179516: Those two are quite superfluous if not explicitly used for some matching. You'd need to show us the code that applies this regex.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a break down of what is happening.

Regex:  `^(PC([Y\\d])|GC([Y\\d])|Y|\\d)\\d{4,5}$`

```
 1. ^        -  Beginning of line  
 2. (        -  Beginning of a capture group
 3. PC       -  Finds `PC` exactly  
 4. ([Y\\d]) -  Creates a capture group for a Y or a single digit (0-9)
 5. |        -  This is an OR statement
 6. GC       -  Finds `GC` exactly
 7. ([Y\\d]) -  Same as 4
 8. |        -  This is an OR statement
 9. Y        -  Finds `Y` exactly
10. |        -  This is an OR statement
11. \\d      -  This looks for a single digit (0-9)
12. )        -  End of capture group.  Lines 3-11 will be in this capture group
13. \\d{4,5} -  This will look any digit exactly 4 or 5 times
14. $        -  End of line
```

There are 3 capture groups in this:

```
1. (PC([Y\\d])|GC([Y\\d])|Y|\\d)
2. ([Y\\d])  (The first one)
3. ([Y\\d])  (The second one)
```

Here is a list of valid matches (any number would be found, I just used 123456 to show how many number places there can be):

- PCY1234
- PCY12345
- PCY1234
- PCY12345
- PC12345
- PC123456
- GC12345
- GC123456
- GCY1234
- GCY12345
- Y1234
- Y12345
- 12345
- 123456

[Here](http://regexr.com?3437t) is a link to RegExr with explanations of the capture groups for each match.

Also, the reason for the double `\` in `\\d` is to escape the `\` for Java.  Not all languages need this, and from what I understand, there are some that need 3. If you notice in the RegExr above, I removed them so RegExr would correctly parse the Regex.

Comment: Thanks, doing this is how I taught myself regex :)

Answer (score 0):

[Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%5E(PC(%5BY%5C%5Cd%5D)%7CGC(%5BY%5C%5Cd%5D)%7CY%7C%5C%5Cd)%5C%5Cd%7B4%2C5%7D%24) is also a fine tool to analyze regular expressions.

[image: Image generated by Regexper]